# Communicating through USB with python

Tags: python, libusb

So, I have a usb to serial cable. The serial part of it is connected to a Raspberry Pi 4, and I want the usb part of it to connect to my windows laptop so they can communicate with each other using python. Windows can detect the device on the port, but it cant read any of the data coming through.

I am currently trying to use libusb1 with python:

```
vendorId = 0x25A7
prodctId = 0xFA67

import usb1
with usb1.USBContext() as context:
    handle = context.openByVendorIDAndProductID(
        vendorId,
        prodctId,
        skip_on_error=True,
    )
    if handle is None:
        print("Device not present, or user is not allowed to access device.")
    with handle.claimInterface(INTERFACE):
        # Do stuff
        pass
```

But with this code, it gives an error that libusb cannot recognize the device.
`usb1.USBErrorNotSupported: LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED [-12]`

Is there a way to make it compatible with libusb? Or is there a different, better way of going about this?

Comment: You would normally talk to a USB-to-serial cable via a module such as PySerial - you wouldn't be dealing with USB directly at all, but rather the COM port that the operating system creates for this particular device.

Comment: Ok. How would I get the COM port corrisponding to the USB?

Comment: Look in Device Manager, see what device shows up when you plug the cable in.

Comment: Ok, so i got COM4 as a port. Now the only problem is that serial.Serial cant find COM4 as a port even when serial.tools.list_ports.comports() says it is there, and the device manager says its there. It says ```A device which does not exist was specified.```